# Scala how to pass in child class and then return the same child class type while getting it generic?

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a method definitions like so

```
def batchCacheable[T: ClassTag](cacheKeys: Seq[CacheKey])(callServiceToFetchValues: Seq[CacheKey] => Try[Map[CacheKey, T]]): Try[Map[CacheKey, T]]
```

Where CacheKey is a trait defined as having a single method called buildCacheKey, and I have a case class that extends that trait and has a id in it as well.

```
trait CacheKey {
  def buildCacheKey: String
}

case class IDCacheKey(id: String) extends CacheKey {
  override def buildCacheKey: String = {
    s"CacheKey:$stringId"
  }
}
```

And the function that I want to use for `callServiceToFetchValues` needs IDCacheKey to get the Id, it looks like this.

```
private def getStringsFromLMS(cacheKeys: Seq[CacheKey]): Try[Map[CacheKey, String]] = { 
    cacheKeys.map(_ -> _.Id) 
}
```

So that it returns a map of Keys -> Ids. The problem is that batchCacheable can only pass into it a Seq of `CacheKey`, but I need it to be a Seq of `IDCacheKey` for the Id. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward solution would be to do something like this:

```
def getStringsFromLMS(cacheKeys: Seq[CacheKey]): Try[Map[CacheKey, String]] = { 
    cacheKeys.collect { case k: IDCacheKey => k.id } 
}
```

This will silently ignore everything that's not `IDCacheKey`. If you'd rather throw an error in case there are keys of wrong type in the input, just replace `.collect` with `.map`.

Either way, this is not *the right* solution. The function declared to expect `CacheKey` should be able to handle *any* instance of `CacheKey`, no matter what type.

At a more general level, a `CacheKey` that doesn't provide enough identity information to fetch the value is not very useful.

Long story short, it looks like your `CacheKey` trait needs an abstract `id` method. That would solve your problem in a natural (and "correct") way.

Alternatively, you could further parameterize `batchCacheable`:

```
   def batchCacheable[T, K <: CacheKey](cacheKeys: Seq[K])(
      callServiceToFetchValues: Seq[K] => Try[Map[K, T]]
   ): Try[Map[K, T]]
```

This lets you declare `getStringsFromLMS` to accept `IDCacheKey`, and still be usable with `batchCacheable`